# Blowing fuse 13 horn, brakes

Tags: honda, brakes, fuse, ridgeline

I have a 2008 honda ridgeline. one day i put it in park and it would not come back out of park. not only that, but the horn would not work, and the brake lights would not work. i found fuse#13 to be blown. i changed the fuse, and it blew it. I disconnected the brake pedal switch, and it still blew fuse # 13. so im figuring a short between fuse box and brake pedal. I take fuse box apart. Everything looks great inside fuse box. I put volt meter on hot side of 13 and get 12 volts. put meter on other side of fuse and get 0 volts...great. now on ohm meter, I go from 0 volt side to ground and get dead short. so i go inside truck to plug for brake switch and ohm every connection in brake plug harness to ground and all four wires show short to ground. any suggestions ? I see where harness goes into firewall, but a complete nightmare after that.

Comment: I also completely disconnected my trailer wiring harness, just incase that might have been the culprit. i also replaced the clock spring in the steering column.

Comment: Check the wiring diagram - that wire must supply more components than just the horn... All you need to do is find the short...

Answer (score 0):

Owners manual will tell you what circuits are protected by fuse 13. Does fuse 13 blow when the brake pedal switch is disconnected? You may learn a Circuit unrelated to the brake lights/brake light switch is also protected by fuse 13 and he is causing the problem. How many amps is the fuse?